# SQL: Use values stored in table_1 to populate a column in table_2 based on a variable listed in table_2

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am very new to sql, taking a class in school but its very basic. I have 2 tables i want to link together somehow, but dont know where to start. i have a month table that lists employees and completed service calls for that month. each employee is paid differently per call and by the type of call. so i have a commissions table that lists each employee, types of service calls, and the data in the columns are dollar amounts that each employee makes for each different type of call. i want to link the employee ids in each table so that i can do something like this...

```
SELECT sum(TypeOfCall) as "Total Commission" 
from December
where TypeOfCall='abc' and EmployeeID='John';
```

but the data stored in the `MothTable` in the `TypeOfCall` column is a variable like '`abc`' or '`cdf`' each variable is listed and given a value in the CommissionsTable. how can i get a sum of the `TypeOfCall` column in the `MonthTable` using the values listed in the `CommissionsTable`?

the actual table, columns and types are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "December" (
    "EmployeeID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "InvoiceType" VARCHAR (6),
    "DR" VARCHAR (8),
    "TypeOfCall" VARCHAR (6),
    "CommissionType" VARCHAR (6),
    "Date DD/MM/YY" VARCHAR (10),
    "InvoiceNumber" INTEGER,
    "InvoiceAmount" FLOAT (6),
    "KeyCode" VARCHAR(20)
)
```

and...

```
CREATE TABLE "Commissions" (
    "EmployeeID" VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "T3" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "T5" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "T7" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "7B" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Other10" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Other12" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Other13" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Other14" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Other15" INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Month Table is a poor choice of Name for what is  actually the ServiceCall table...

Comment: Can you give us the two tables and their respective columns and types?

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is `SUM(CommissionsTable.value)` (substitute the correct column name) with an `INNER JOIN` between the month's table and `CommissionsTable`.

```
SELECT
  December.TypeOfCall,
  SUM(CommissionsTable.value) AS "Total Commission"
FROM
  December
  /* Substitute the correct column name for ComissionsTable.TypeOfCall */
  INNER JOIN CommissionsTable WHERE December.TypeOfCall = CommissionsTable.TypeOfCall
WHERE
  December.TypeOfCall = 'abc' 
  AND EmployeeID = 'John'
/* GROUP BY needed if you were retrieving more than just 'abc' */
GROUP BY December.TypeOfCall
```

It is *not* appropriate to have a separate table for each month, however. Instead, your table listing calls should include a date value for each call, along with its type and `EmployeeID`.  Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE calls (
  EmployeeID VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  TypeOfCall CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  CallDate INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

calls table store records in just one or many table depend on the number of records and data save period, if the acount is very very larg , partition or mutiplue tables are good choice.
create index on December.TypeOfCall may tune perf.